# Tracing a C# console window that will not close

Tags: c#, console, windows-xp

Ok, this is a somewhat odd question, but I found a problem similar to these:

[Debugged Program Window Won't Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275251/debugged-program-window-wont-close)

[Unable to kill instances of cmd.exe on Win XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920442/unable-to-kill-instances-of-cmd-exe-on-win-xp?lq=1)

[How to close an "orphaned" console window that was opened from within visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335671/how-to-close-an-orphaned-console-window-that-was-opened-from-within-visual-stu)

I've found this problem recently on a production environment, oddly enough this machine did not have VS installed, and I was not debugging, but the behavior was exactly the same. The only thing I've found that really worked was using PSKill (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683) to close csrss.exe (which controls all console windows). This, obviously created a crash, but I was able to reboot the machine. I found this particularly helpful, provided such machine was not physically accessible.

The box details are:

Pentium 4, 1GB RAM, Windows XP SP2 (mind you, this is not my ideal setup, but not for me to decide :P)

I would, however, like to know if there is a way to prevent this from happening again.

I want to emphasize, there is NO VS installed on this particular machine, and the program running is not a Debug build, but a Release one. I did try Microsoft's KB 982551 hotfix but to no avail.

The particulars for the app are like this: It opens and connects to another process via named pipes, and then it will close if communication is interrupted or you close the console window via the X button or typing 'q'. Apparently the named pipe went down somewhere along the way, and the app stayed alive (which does not happen in any other cases, just this one).

Can you think of a way of tracing/reproducing this behavior in a more easily controlled environment?

I'll be happy to post any part of the code if you ask for it, I'm not doing it right now because there are like 5 different files that do the full job.

Edit: Oh, I forgot to tell you, the target machine does not have KB 978037, just in case you were wondering.

Comment: Is there a good reason this isn't a Windows service? This certainly does not belong as a console application.

Comment: Well, yes, this application is opened only when you need to check on the status of the other process, that controls specialized hardware, and the devices status.

Comment: So, if a user opens it, did the user just walk away and leave the console window open after executing their task?

Comment: Apparently so... sadly I was called when the problem appeared, not before. I agree this shouldn't have happened, but you know how final users can be :P This is a 'specialty' application, mind you, but the users are not always properly introduced to it.